# how to get output another pattern using mango aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

hello my question is how to get last four months records from database.i got the output but  not getting my expected pattern  so how to do this can any one help me to solve this.

```
db.Air_pollution.aggregate([
    {$match:
    {CREATE_DATE:{$lte:new Date(),
    $gte:new Date(new Date().setDate(new 
    Date().getDate()-120))}}},
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id:{month:{$month:"$CREATE_DATE"},
            year:{$year:"$CREATE_DATE"}
        },
        avgofozone:{$avg:"$OZONE"}
    }
},
{
    $sort:{"year":-1}
},
{
    $project:{
        year:'$_id.year',
        avgofozone:'$avgofozone',
        month:'$_id.month',_id:0
    }
}
])
```

Output is:

```
{ "avgofozone" : 21.07777777777778, "year" : 2018, "month" : 2 }
{ "avgofozone" : 17.8, "year" : 2018, "month" : 3 }
{ "avgofozone" : 17.8, "year" : 2018, "month" : 1 }
```

Expected output:

```
zone_type       year        january   febravary           march
avgofozone     2018         17.8      21.07777           17.8
```

Comment: any one please suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the data you need, rather than trying to get it exactly how you need it from MongoDB, why not just format it in the application layer?

Some simple JavaScript to do that:

```js
const months = [
  'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May',
  'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
  'October', 'November', 'December'
];

function monthNumToName(monthnum) {
  return months[monthnum - 1];
}

const results = [{
  "avgofozone": 21.07777777777778,
  "year": 2018,
  "month": 2
}, {
  "avgofozone": 17.8,
  "year": 2018,
  "month": 3
}, {
  "avgofozone": 17.8,
  "year": 2018,
  "month": 1
}];

const statsByYear = results.reduce((a, c) => {
  const {
    year,
    month,
    avgofozone
  } = c;
  if (!a[year])
    a[year] = {
      zone_type: 'avgofozone',
      year,
      [monthNumToName(month)]: avgofozone
    }
  else a[year][monthNumToName(month)] = avgofozone
  return a;
}, {});
const formatted = Object.keys(statsByYear).map(k => {
  return statsByYear[k];
});

console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: @ Aaron Rumery    its working but any possible write only mongo aggregation like same output

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that, but this kind of formatting really belongs in the application layer, not in some crazy DB query to accomplish that. Formatting in the application layer is much more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: @ Aaron Rumery  ok how to fix this java script code with mongo aggregation any possible